# Cucumber Test runner issue

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I have below format for test runner but it is giving no feature file found while running the junit runner.Please attached the screenshot of  locations of the step definition[image: screenshot] and feature file

```
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
        features ={"C:\\Users\\workspace\\Project3\\src\\qa2qe\\Features\\shipping.feature"},
        format = {"pretty"},
                tags = {"@testscenario1"}

                )

public class ShippingTest {

}
```

Comment: It looks like you have posted two copies of `ShippingTest.java`.  Could you please post all relevant files, and do so as code snippets rather than screenshots, so it is easier to read and copy?

Comment: try features = "src/qa2qe/Features/shipping.feature", don't use {} and check shipping.feature file has the tag @testscenario1, if feature file not has such tag, it will not run the feature file.

Comment: Please share the content of the ``shipping.feature`` file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import cucumber.junit.Cucumber; 

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(
        features ={"C:\\Users\\workspace\\Project3\\src\\qa2qe\\Features\\shipping.feature"},
        format = {"pretty"},
        tags = "@testscenario1")

public class ShippingTest 
{
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).